# How to get image from SharePoint document library into thumbnail card of messaging extension of bot framework

Tags: botframework, sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I'm having a SharePoint document library which contains some icons. And i'm having a azure web app bot used for messaging extension using bot framework. In messaging extension preview thumbnail card i need to load the icons from SharePoint library.
Both SharePoint document library and Azure bot are on different tenant and users are also different.
SO when i'm trying to load icons from SharePoint library its giving me unauthorized error due to different tenant and users. 
Is there any way to pass base64 string to thumbnail card in to load the image instead of url.

I have tried to convert image from SharePoint document library to base64 string but didn't got a way to pass that base64 string to messaging extension.

I need to show images from sharepoint document library into thumbnail card of bot framework.

Comment: Are you able to download the SharePoint images? If yes then, in [Thumbnail Card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-reference#example-thumbnail-card) you can pass your base64 image data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 approaches you can implement.

1. Store images to Azure blob storage and use static url from the blob. You can use SAS key for security.
2. Other approach is storing images to SharePoint doc library as you listed in question then you are getting base64 value of image and store that value to a variable and use it in DataUri as below
   `string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}",Convert.ToBase64String(photoBytes));`